# Why dispatch.fetch is very Slow in Hunk while retrieving data from Cassandra?

Tags: datastax, splunk

I am connecting my hunk application(6.4) to datastax cassandra 3.1 to get the results for monitoring and the results took consistently 5 seconds to render though the table has data in hundreds.
I have verified my CassandraERP Connector class also which is hardly taking time in mili seconds to return the response.Could anyone help me in getting this clarified.

Execution costs
    Duration (seconds) Component Invocations Input count Output count
    0.00 command.fields 4 1 1
    0.00 command.search 4 1 1
    0.00 command.search.filter 4 - -
    2.02 command.stdin 3 - 1
    2.00 command.stdin.cpd2sr 2 1 1
    0.00 command.stdin.calcfields 1 1 1
    2.00 command.stdin.cpd2sr.blocked 1 - -
    0.00 command.stdin.kv 1 1 1
    0.00 command.stdin.tags 1 1 1
    0.00 command.stdin.typer 1 1 1
    0.00 command.stdin.fieldalias 1 1 1
    0.00 command.stdin.lookups 1 1 1
    0.00 dispatch.check_disk_usage 1 - -
    0.06 dispatch.createdSearchResultInfrastructure 1 - -
    0.04 dispatch.evaluate 1 - -
    0.04 dispatch.evaluate.search 1 - -
    4.08 dispatch.fetch 6 - -
    0.00 dispatch.localSearch 1 - -
    0.00 dispatch.preview 1 - -
    0.00 dispatch.readEventsInResults 1 - -
    0.00 dispatch.stream.local 1 - -
    0.00 dispatch.timeline 6 - -
    0.03 dispatch.writeStatus 8 - -
    0.01 startup.configuration 1 - -
    0.03 startup.handoff 1 - -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basil, this should have been asked in Splunk Answers, not here

A fundamental concept to grasp about Hunk is that it keeps splunkd's code on the target (Hadoop datanodes, Cassandra, etc) which gets initialised when you do a search and *only* the Mapping stage of Map Reduce actually happens there
- The output of the Map gets streamed back to the Search Head for it to Reduce

And this is why you're seeing those high dispatch.fetch values - it's waiting for the map results

Comment: Thanks for your response!. Is there anyway can we reduce the high dispatch.fetch values?